# How to fix a black screen (bricked) after rooting an encrypted device

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, rooting, 4.3-jelly-bean, encryption, unbricking

Phone: Samsung Galaxy S3 (GT-I9300)

Per work policy to add an exchange account I had to encrypt my phone. After doing so, I needed to root it to create a swap partition as it was constantly running out of RAM. I did what I had done in the past which was to flash CF-Auto-Root with Odin3. After the process finished, the phone restarted and I was shown the usual screen for entering the PIN/Password, so I did and it accepted it showing the unlocked Android icon, but instead of booting to the OS, it froze on a black screen. I have tried flashing the stock firmware, which has had no effect. I have managed to flash the ClockworkMod Recovery, but since everything's encrypted I could not get access to any data.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up flashing the Stock ROM (using sammobile.com) back again and using the Stock Recovery to do a factory reset as the Team Win Recovery format didn't do anything.
That did the trick, but of course all data is gone too. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to wipe your data/cache + dalvik?
For my experience, sometimes the black-screen is due to a bad-flashing procedure (not your fault) when something goes wrong.
If you did not tried yet, try and let me know!

Regards,

Luca

Comment: I've tried wiping the cache + dalvik, no change. I'd rather avoid wiping the data and lose it till I see that I have no other choice.

I've also wiped the /system and then reflashed it with the Stock ROM, no change.
Also, checking the ClockWorkMod Recovery log I see that when attempting to wipe the dalvik-cache, it couldn't find the folders: '/data/dalvik-cache', '/cache/dalvik-cache' and '/sd-ext/dalvik-cache'.


Is there a way I could backup everything (perhaps via ADB), wipe the /data and then later attempt to restore?

Comment: OK, I now wiped /data, /cache and /dalvik-cache using Team Win Recovery, and there's been no change at all. I still get the screen to type in my password and when I do, I get the black screen again.

Comment: I ended up flashing the Stock ROM back again and using the Stock Recovery to do a factory reset as the Team Win Recovery format didn't do anything.
That did the trick, but of course all data is gone too. Oh well.